# My show function is not working in Laravel. URL shows the particular id, but in the page data won't come

Tags: php, laravel

When I click on a particular product on the products page, it directed me to the single product page. Particular product ID also showing in the URL. But data won't be passed. My single product page doesn't show the particular product data.

This is my Controller.

```
SingleProductController.php


<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;

class SingleProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Product $product)
    {
        $arr['product'] = $product;
        return view('singleproducts')->with($arr);

    }

    
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

   
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    
    public function show($id)
    { 
    

        $product = Product::find($id);
       
        return view ('singleproducts')->with(['product'=>$product]);
    }

   
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

   
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This is my blade file.

```
singleproducts.blade


@extends('layouts.singleproducts')
@section('content')

   <h2 class="font-size-25 text-lh-1dot2">{{ $product ['prod_name'] }}  </h2>

 <div class="mb-4">
                                    <div class="d-flex align-items-baseline">
                                        <ins class="font-size-36 text-decoration-none">{{ $product ['prod_price'] }}</ins>
                                        <del class="font-size-20 ml-2 text-gray-6">$2,299.00</del>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
@endsection
```

This is my route.

```
web.php

Route::get('/singleproducts', 'SingleProductController@index')->name('singleproducts');
Route::get('/singleproducts/{id}', 'SingleProductController@show')->name('eachproduct');
```

Why my show function is not working?

Comment: beause error in show function

Comment: public function show($id)
    { 
            $product = Product::find($id);
        return view('singleproducts', ['product' => $product]); 
    }

Comment: I edited above my code, please have a look. This is also not working.

Comment: Please share your single page product route

Comment: Route::resource('/products', 'ProductsController');
Route::get('/singleproducts', 'SingleProductController@index')->name('singleproducts');
Route::get('/eachproduct/{id}', 'SingleProductController@show')->name('eachproduct');

Comment: ok make it full demo check it.perfectly worked in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

route.php

```
Route::get('/singleproducts', 'SingleProductController@index')->name('singleproducts');
Route::get('/eachproduct/{id}', 'SingleProductController@show')->name('eachproduct');
```

Product List Page

```
@if (isset($products) && count($products) > 0)
    @foreach ($products as $product)
    <div class="blog_box_inner" style="cursor: pointer;" >
        <h1 class="blog_inner_heading">
            <a href="/eachproduct/{{$product['id']}}" class="blog_readmore_link">
                {{$product['prod_name']}}
            </a>
        </h1>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    @endif
```

Single page

```
<h2 class="font-size-25 text-lh-1dot2">{{ $product['prod_name']}}  </h2>
```

Controller

```
public function index() {
    $products = Product::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    return view('')->with(compact('products'));
}

public function show($id) {
    $product = Product::find($id);
     return view('')->with(compact('product'));
}
```

Hope fully it will help to you easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public function show(Product $product)
{ 
    return view ('singleproducts', compact('product'));
}
```

and pass in route

```
Route::get('/eachproduct/{product}', 'SingleProductController@show')->name('eachproduct');
```

and in your view page get product data as

```
singleproducts.blade


@extends('layouts.singleproducts')
@section('content')

<h2 class="font-size-25 text-lh-1dot2">{{ $product->prod_name }}  </h2>
<div class="mb-4">
<div class="d-flex align-items-baseline">
<ins class="font-size-36 text-decoration-none">{{ $product->prod_price }}</ins>
<del class="font-size-20 ml-2 text-gray-6">$2,299.00</del>
</div>
</div>

@endsection
```

It will auto find your product on base of id.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
return view('singleproducts',compact('product'));
```

In your view use like this

```
<h2 class="font-size-25 text-lh-1dot2">{{ $product->prod_name }}  </h2>
<ins class="font-size-36 text-decoration-none">{{ $product->prod_price }}</ins>
```